# How to pronounce Silas Lapham's last name

Tags: william-dean-howells, the-rise-of-silas-lapham

How would the author of *The Rise of Silas Lapham* have pronounced the last name of his title character? Please provide supporting evidence for your answer.

Comment: Like Chatham, only with a /p/ instead of a /t/. The "ham" is a suffix on "lap" and "chat", so the "ph" and "th" are pronounced like "uphill" and "courthouse".

Comment: @PeterShor: how do you know that is how the author would have pronounced it?

Comment: I don't know how the author would have pronounced it. I just know this was the traditional pronunciation of Lapham. So either the author pronounced it this way, or he was pronouncing it "wrong".

Comment: One can similarly ask how Dickens pronounced the first name of the heroine of *Bleak House*, Esther Summerson. Since "Ester" was the standard English pronunciation at the time (it still is), one would assume that he used /t/ and not the spelling pronunciation with /θ/. Otherwise he would have been pronouncing it "wrong". I think in both cases the assumption that the author used the standard pronunciation is the only reasonable one to make.

Comment: @PeterShor A final `/əm/` is plausible in a British English context, but are American names ending on 'ham' consistently pronounced with the same ending? See [How is the name of the town Hingham, Massachusetts, pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/529775/163363).

Comment: In Massachusetts, *Dedham, Needham, Hingham* and *Chatham* can be pronounced with  pronounced with /əm/ (no /h/) at the end, but *Framingham* usually ends with /hæm/. But other regions of the U.S. could pronounce these names differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we look at British place names ending in 'ham', we see the following:

- Allingham is pronounced `/ˈælɪŋəm/`.
- Altrincham: `/ˈɔːltrɪŋəm/`.
- Birmingham: `/ˈbɜːmɪŋəm/`.
- Buckingham: `/ˈbʌkɪŋəm/`.
- Cunningham: `/ˈkʌnɪŋəm/`.
- Chatham: `/ˈtʃætəm/`.
- **Clapham**: `/ˈklæpəm/`.
- Evesham: `/ˈiːvʃəm/`.
- Gillingham: `/ˈdʒɪlɪŋəm/`.
- Heysham: `/ˈhiːʃəm/`.
- Immingham: `/ˈɪmɪŋəm/`.
- Newham: `/ˈnjuːəm/`.
- Nottingham: `/ˈnɒtɪŋəm/`.
- Oldham: `/ˈoʊldəm/`
- Sandringham: `/ˈsændrɪŋəm/`.
- Tottenham: `/ˈtɑtənəm/`.
- Wrexham: `/ˈrɛksəm/`.

When we look at British family names, see see for example the following:

- Bentham: `/ˈbɛnθəm/`.
- Botham: `/ˈbəʊθəm/`.
- Gresham : `/ˈɡrɛʃəm/`.
- Pelham: `/ˈpɛləm/`.

When we look at American place names, we see a different pattern:

- Bellingham: `/ˈbɛlɪŋˌhæm/`.
- Framingham: `/ˈfreɪmɪŋˌhæm/`.
- Bingham:`/ˈbɪŋəm/`.
- Waltham is pronounced `/ˈwɔlθəm/` or `/ˈwɔlˌθæm/`.

When we look at American family names, we find the following examples:

- [Lewis H. **Lapham**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_H._Lapham): `/ˈlæpəm/`.
- [Jonathan Lethem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Lethem) (admitted not 'ham'): `/ˈliːθəm/`.

The noun [gingham](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gingham) is pronounced `/ˈgiŋ-əm/`.

(Source for the phonemic transcriptions: [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/), except where I have included a link to Wikipedia or Merriam Webster.)

One thing that is very consistent is that names consisting of two syllables end on `/əm/`; the only exception is Waltham.
So unless William Dean Howells intentionally wanted to diverge from this pattern, the name of the character Lapham was pronounced **`/ˈlæpəm/`**.